# Looking for a machine's breakdown dataset

Tags: dataset, prediction

I am searching for a dataset that contains a machine's (any mechanical machine) operational variables (e.g. vibration, temprature, etc. ) versus it's operational status (e.g. functioning, malfunction, breakdown).
I have failed to find such dataset with googling.
Is there such a dataset?

Comment: Would a practice set be ok, or do you need real data?

Comment: Hi; no I want real data.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the NSSDC NASA data of 550 space spacecraft

- https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nssdc/obtaining_data.html
- https://pds.jpl.nasa.gov/

Comment: Is there a specific link to the data set you are referencing?

Comment: I will look for it ;) but i'm sure it's there somewhere i worked with it before

Comment: Please let me know if you find it! I'm interested but couldn't find it myself.